# A session cookie exists on the users machine, but there are so session variables in existance?

Tags: php, session, session-variables, session-cookies

I feel like I am at my wits end trying to suss out a problem with my session variables in my buying process, but I'll have another go on here trying find help to solve it!

When a user gets a quote on my on my results page, I set multiple session variables to help in the latter stages of the buying process. One of these is named "sessionnumber". It refers to one DB Id field and helps me identify the current quote.

At the top of every buying process page I have the following code:

```
session_name("mywebsitesystem");
session_start();
```

On my second page, the customer details page, I have some code which checks the existence of "sessionnumber" session variable. It always exists when I do test quotes and users are able to buy from our website. But I get an alert email every time a customer hits the second page and that session variable is blank.

We get an alarmingly large amount of these incidents a day. I originally thought they were users who did not have cookies enabled, but in the alert email I send a loop of all session variables present, and all cookies present.

The session variables are non existent, but the cookie "mywebsitesystem" DOES exist.

I have no idea how that is possible? How can that cookie be set on the results page along with the session variables, yet when they move onto the next stage there isn't a single session variable?

At the very least, can some one suggest some more debug I can try if no solution can be thought of? The fact I cannot duplicate this problem myself is so annoying!

Could my server be doing something to these sessions - so the cookie exists on the machine, but the server doesn't return any information for it?

UPDATE 1:

```
$conn = $db->pdoConnect();
$sql =  "INSERT INTO sessions (DateTimeCreated) VALUES ('".date("Y/m/d H:i:s")."') ";
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);

$sessionnumber = $conn->lastInsertId(); 

$_SESSION['sessionnumber'] = $sessionnumber;
```

Comment: You have to start the session on every page you want to access session variables on. Are you calling that code on the page that sends the email?

Comment: Is the domain name the same? Is there a change from http to https or back? Does E_NOTICE show anything when session_ start() is run?

Comment: @sharf - yes I am. The code that sends the email is in a class and function that is executed on the customer page itself. jdog - all quote results are on https and the customer page is https too. All URL's include www. so I don't think it's that :(

Comment: Is it possible the part of the code where the session variable set is being bypassed somehow?

Comment: Hi @sharf, please check my UPDATE 1 in the question. Could there be a problem with $conn->lastInsertId(); - in which case my session number variable would be blank. But it doesn't explain why NO session variables appear in the alert email when I look through them.

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with PDO, but there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with it. Perhaps you could send another email when the session variables are set, so you can includes $sessionnumber and $_SESSION['sessionnumber'] to see if both are being set, and if not, maybe find your problem.